# Please can anyone tell me how i can model the areas in the red box

Tags: modeling, modifiers, normal-map

I am trying to model the side wall light in the reference image can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your image as *Reference*, extrude vertices along the shape:

[image]

Fill the faces:

[image]

Extrude upwards:

[image]

Extrude downwards to dig the sculpture, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful ❤❤